Cannot connect to SQLLite in MAUI (.NET 8)
I have an app created in maui (.NET 7). Now I tried to update to .NET 8 and updated ALL NuGet packages.
From now, I'm unable to open connection to SQLLite internal DB
    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    string sPath = BCDataConstants.DatabasePath;
    // value = /data/user/0/it.gattoneroph.photoapp/files/CAPhoto.db 
    // cames from =>       Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "CAPhoto.db");


    Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(sPath, Flags);
    // no error but "System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception." in ALL properties

    CreateTableResult s= Database.CreateTableAsync<Tab_TabellaDatabase>().Result;
// here crashes

VS 2022 on win 11 + emulator API 30
.NET 8
NuGet Packages

SQLitePCLRaw.Core 2.1.8
SQLite 3.13.0
SQLlite.PCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3 2.1.8
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3 2.1.8
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green 2.1.8
System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.118
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl 2.1.8

What can I do?
Tried everything  I know.
(EDIT)

Connection properties after constructor
Stacktrace when  I try to create table

11:07:55:509   [DOTNET] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection'
threw an exception.)
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]  ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception.
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]  ---> System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3 failed
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..cctor()
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionWithLock..ctor(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString)
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.Entry..ctor(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString)
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.GetConnectionAndTransactionLock(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString, Object& transactionLock)
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.GetConnection(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString)
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.GetConnection()
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.<>c__DisplayClass33_01[[SQLite.CreateTableResult, SQLite-net, Version=1.9.172.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<WriteAsync>b__0() 11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[SQLite.CreateTableResult, SQLite-net,
Version=1.9.172.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null]].InnerInvoke()
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__281_0(Object obj)
11:07:55:509   [DOTNET]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback> callback, Object state)
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionWithLock..ctor(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString)
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.Entry..ctor(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString)
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.GetConnectionAndTransactionLock(SQLiteConnectionString> connectionString, Object& transactionLock)
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteConnectionPool.GetConnection(SQLiteConnectionString
connectionString)
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.GetConnection()
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.get_Tracer()
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[SQLite.CreateTableResult, SQLite-net, Version=1.9.172.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) 11:07:55:509  [DOTNET]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[[SQLite.CreateTableResult, SQLite-net,
Version=1.9.172.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].get_Result()
11:07:55:509  [DOTNET] at PhotoApp.Classes.Database.BCDataConnection..ctor() in C:\Progetti


"tried to update to c# 8.0" - you mean ".Net 8", don't you? Not really C# 8.0 ...

Database.CreateTableAsync<Tab_TabellaDatabase>().Result - suspicious but probably not the problem ... System.TypeInitializationException - can you post a stacktrace? What type is Database declared as?

@Fildor done (edited post).. yes sorry (.net 8.0)

Just for good measure: Did you 1. Clean-Build the Project/Solution 2. Close IDE 3. Manually delete (the correct) /bin folder 4. Reopen IDE 5. Build Solution ?

Yes.. it's one of the first thing I've tried :(

VTable setup of Type ??? failed.  can be caused by upgrading one of your projects to depend on a newer version of a library and neglecting to do that for all you projects. Please check the reference  of installed nuget packages, if they have same version. Please create a new emulator and run your application, is that working?

Found a solution...
I've removed ALL sqllite NuGet packages and installed ONLY 2

sqlite-net-pcl v. 1.9.172
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green v2.1.8

also changed DbName "CAPhoto.db" to "CAPhoto.db3" and dbpath to FileSystem.AppDataDirectory
Now tables will be created successfully
